# Runtime error using arcpy module

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, python-2.7, runtimeerror

I'm writing an automatization script that auto imports new line features. This has to be done for ~40k line features. The program runs pretty well since i had to optimatize it quite a lot to meet speed standards and to avoid memory errors.

I have one existing feature dataset in *.gdb that represents roads in my country . I then get a shapefile that represents new features. The scipt then takes each feature of a shapefile and creates new temporary shape with only that feature so i can select by location for only one feature. Geometry of the selected data is then saved as python dict for faster processing. That single feature is also saved as dict with geometry. Then it runs some self created functions for fixing topology(intersections, deletes overlaying features, snaping) and finally updates attributes with some of new attributes from shapefile and some attributes that are copied from overlaying features that were deleted.

The whole "program" is 1000+ rows long and seperated in more files for better code organization so that specific code snippet might be not useful.

Every so often though the script runs into runtime error. What is strange about this error is that there is no trackback or anything. It just shows the "Runtime Error" in red and nothing else.

I should say that this error only happens every so often but it breaks my code stability.

Does anyone have similar error experiance using arcpy and what could be done to avoid this error since I can't even handle the exeption since i get no feedback to the exact line in which the error happens?

What i'm trying to ask is if anyone from SE comunity got this "blank" error in their work with arcpy.

I'm using ArcGis 10.4 with python 2.7

Here is the picture of error message.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please could you edit your question to include some more details to help users solve your problem? Perhaps the code itself and some details on what it's doing (ie where it's importing from, formats, etc.)

Comment: I tried to explain some more but didn't post any particular code since i dont really know which part of the code could be the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following things:

- Look at where the AddError is happening, if at all.
- Check the memory usage isn't hitting too much RAM. I have noticed problems around 1.5+ GB.
- Check to see if the traceback has been disabled, or anything really discussed in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784849/in-python-how-do-i-print-an-error-message-without-printing-a-traceback-and-clos
- Figure out where this is actually breaking and see if you can fix it. Post the relevant code. Write in a logger, or add AddMessage statements to it to figure out what line it is failing on.

Answer (score 0):

So I have been testing some more. This error accured randomly around the code when i debugged using print statements.

What I figured out (it is kind of funny) is that this error happens only when I had open another instance of ArcMap GUI so i guess this could be the reason for this strange error. I haven't had this error since i started closing multiple instances of ArcMap.